# Change outgoing IP address using Curl

Tags: php, curl, ip-address

I am connecting to a server with several IP addresses using PHP and CURLOPT_PROXY (SOCK5) from my local machine.
What I want to do is to be able to change the outgoing IP address on the remote server.
No matter what IP I use to connect to my remote server, the outgoing IP (Remote server to internet) is the same.

I used the command ssh -N -D 0.0.0.0:1080 localhost on the server to setup a Socks5 proxy

Comment: Do you have access to the "remote server"? Is it actually running a Socks 5 proxy, and/or is it your own implementation? If not what software is it using to proxy with?

Comment: Yes i have access to the remote server and i used the command ssh -N -D 0.0.0.0:1080 localhost to setup a Socks5 proxy. I'm using PHP and CURL to connect to this proxy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The SOCKS5 protocol itself does not support requesting to bind to a specific IP address. You can see an overview of the [SOCKS5 protocol on Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOCKS#SOCKS5).

There may be proxy software that supports binding to a specific outgoing IP address based on username. You will have to investigate this yourself.

If using different ports is acceptable, you could request ssh itself to bind to a specific IP address.

```
ssh -N -b 1.1.1.1 -D 0.0.0.0:1080 localhost
ssh -N -b 1.1.1.2 -D 0.0.0.0:1081 localhost
ssh -N -b 1.1.1.3 -D 0.0.0.0:1082 localhost
...
```

In summary, it is not possible to achieve this using ssh on its own, you will need to have it bind to multiple IP addresses or ports itself, or investigate other proxy software.

Comment: Thanks Leigh, I tried the command ssh -b (IP HERE) -N -D 0.0.0.0:1080  and it doesn't work, the shell response is:
usage: ssh [....

Comment: try `ssh -N -b <IP> -D 0.0.0.0:1080`

Comment: missing `localhost` from the end.

Comment: Also, I believe you can do round-robin load balancing with iptables. You could bind your proxies to different IP addresses, and use iptables to redirect inc-ip:1080 to out-ip-1:1080, out-ip-2:1080, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Didn't understand your question clearly, but from the title, I would say, please use `CURLOPT_INTERFACE`

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php